# File Lock on Linux

Tags: bash, file, locking

So there are 2 scripts: A and B, both want to write to the same file. It's possible to both scripts want to write to the file at the same time. How can I lock the file? While script A is writing to the file, script B has to wait till the file is get unlocked.

I tried this:

```
while [ -f $LOCK ]
do
    sleep 0.1
    done
touch $LOCK
#action
rm $LOCK
```

The problem with the script above that it's possible, that both of A and B is looking for the $LOCK at the same time, and they cant find't to start writing.
Any help?

Comment: flock, lockfile, or [dotlockfile](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/liblockfile)

Comment: This isn't really a problem easily solved in a portable, robust way with a script.  In other words, a shell script is really the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Script A are open file then set attribute `chattr +i test.txt` and after script A are done use `chattr -i test.txt`.

For example:

Script A

```
chattr +i test.txt
tail -n 50 /var/log/maillog > test.txt
chattr -i test.txt
```

Script B

```
chattr +i test.txt
tail -n 50 /var/log/messages > test.txt
chattr -i test.txt
```

Comment: Won't `chattr +i text.txt` prevent *any* process from modifying the file?  If so, that won't act as the *write* lock that the OP wants.

Comment: Nobody can change this file (as a root) during this flag is exists. So you can use 'PID' for locking modification, like 'echo $$'

Comment: That won't work. First, "Script A are open file then set attribute `chattr +i test.txt`" introduces a race condition where script B can *also* open the file then call `chattr ...`.  Second, the code posted does not properly synchronize multiple `chattr ...` calls. For example, if there are two calls to `chattr +i ...`, there probably should be two calls to `chattr -i ...` to reset the attribute properly.  But that isn't the way the `chattr` utiliity works.

Comment: Anybody can open the file but nobody can change it. Than you need to use lock file or find process script A or B. PS command or find PIDs (kill -0 $PID).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is:

```
echo $$ >> lockfile
locked_by=$(head -1 lockfile)
if [ $$ = $locked_by ] ; then
    echo "Hurray! the file is mine!"
    #do stuff
    rm lockfile
else
    echo "$locked_by has the lock, sorry"
fi
```

the `echo $$ >> lockfile` is, most of the time, atomic enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kill -0` and `if` construction. For example:

```
kill -0 $lockPid
if [[ $? == 0 ]];then
    echo "File locked"
    break
else
    bash script2.sh
fi
```